# How to get the sub-process pid in the expect shell script, after spawn

Tags: shell, expect, spawn

Part of the script **a.exp**:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# ..... 
spawn ssh -qTfnN -D $port $user@$host
expect "*assword:*"
# .....
```

How can I get the **pid** of sub-process "ssh".

If I execute these in bash shell, not in a script file, the result is

```
expect1.1> spawn ssh name@host
spawn ssh name@host
2188
expect1.2>
```

*2188* is the sub-process pid.

And how to use **exp_pid** command  in the expect shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is something like this:

```
spawn ssh name@host
set pid [exp_pid]
puts "PID: $pid"
```

Answer (score 2):

[This man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) says:

> spawn returns the UNIX process id. If no process is spawned, 0 is returned.

I.e. you can do:

```
set pid [spawn ssh -qTfnN -D $port $user@$host]
```

---

You can also use `exp_pid` as [jcollado demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261178/5728089). The same man page explains that:

> `exp_pid [-i spawn_id]`
>   returns the process id corresponding to the currently spawned process. If the `-i` flag is used, the pid returned corresponds to that of the given spawn id.