# How to run bash process in parallel in mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line

I am trying to run a few commands through the bash script in mac.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

testDirectory='/Users/jxxxx/Desktop/xxxxx/mad_team_training/Trimify/backend-operations/tests/pagination-integration.test.js'
deleteScript='/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/xxxxx/mad_team_training/Trimify/backend-operations/scripts/test-delete-table.sh'
echo "$testDirectory"
cd ../
sls offline start
open -a Terminal.app $deleteScript
RUNNING_PID=$!
kill ${RUNNING_PID}
```

Problem

- `sls offline start` will require mfa and then logs the output continously on terminal( which is needed)
- But i want to run deleteScript in seperate terminal once sls offline starts but it is not running in the new terminal with current script, **somehow it starts only after sls process is killed**
- once delete script is over, kill `sls offline start` process

Comment: Does `sls offline start` background itself? For example, if you run it interactively, does it immediately give you a new shell prompt (and then probably write over it with log output), or does it not let you back into your shell until it's finished (/killed)? (Also, be aware that running `open` does *not* wait for the other program to finish; it starts it, then immediately goes on to the next command).

Comment: sls offline start ask for mfa and then it does not let me back into my shell until it's finished/killed.
open does not wait for the other program to finish; it starts it, then immediately goes on to the next command).This is exactly what i am, looking for by the time sls offline ask for mfa and start, i want to run my delete script after 5-10 seconds delay

Comment: `expect` could probably do the job. First steps : [background process with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916201/background-spawned-process-in-expect), [get pid with expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260633/how-to-get-the-sub-process-pid-in-the-expect-shell-script-after-spawn)

Comment: mfa code is generated from my registered device how will expect work in that case? @Aserre

Comment: If I understood correctly : 1) `sls offline start` shows an input asking for your mfa code 2) you take it from your device 3) the program shows you a confirmation line like `mfa code correct` ?